# R: Trouble coding loop function for feature extraction?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, feature-extraction

I have two vectors:

```
 EventDate <- c("2018-10-31", "2018-11-16", "2018-12-02")
 ThirtyDaysPriorEvent <- c("2018-10-01", "2018-10-17", "2018-11-02")
```

I need help writing a loop function for the following workflow:

1. Loop through the vectors to identify dates in the same index positions,
   and store them in variables. For example, the first pair of dates
   would be EventDate[1] & ThirtyDaysPriorEvent[1].  For the sample data, the values are "2018-10-31" and "2018-10-01".
2. Use the variables as date arguments in dplyr's filter
       function. Query db for all activities that occurred 30 days prior to each event date.  Store the results in a dataframe called Activities30dys.
3. Compute sums of columns in the Activities30dys dataframe.
4. Create a new column in the Events dataframe using computed values from     step #3.

This is the result I want to achieve:

A new column named "d" in the Events dataframe derived from aggregating values in column "x" in the Activities dataframe.

```
      date  a    b     c     d
2018-10-31 42 60.5 152.4 16.63
2018-11-16 54 54.1 151.6 16.63
2018-12-02 63 74.2 153.5 19.95
```

However, this is as far as I've gotten:

```
 library(dplyr)

 # identifies dates in the same index position for each vector & stores results in variables
 e <- EventDate[1]
 e30 <- ThirtyDaysPriorEvent[1]

 # uses variables to filter Activities dataframe
 Activities30Dys <- Activities %>%
   filter(date > e30 & date < e) 

 # computes sum of x activity done 30 days prior to event date
 sum(Activities30Dys$x, na.rm = TRUE)

 # adds new column (d) to Events dataframe
 Events %>%
   mutate()
```

Here's my reproduceable data:

```
     Events <- structure(list(date = c("2018-10-31", "2018-11-16", "2018-12-02"
), a = c(42L, 54L, 63L), b = c(60.5, 54.1, 74.2), c = c(152.4, 
151.6, 153.5)), .Names = c("date", "a", "b", "c"), row.names = 
c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

     Activities <- structure(list(date = c("2018-09-18", "2018-09-19", "2018-10-21", 
"2018-10-21", "2018-10-24", "2018-10-26", "2018-10-27", "2018-11-18", 
"2018-11-19", "2018-11-21", "2018-11-24", "2018-11-26", "2018-11-27", 
"2018-12-05"), x = c(3.43, 3.16, 3.2, 3.27, 3.74, 3.2, 3.22, 
3.43, 3.16, 3.2, 3.74, 3.2, 3.22, 3.02), y = c(132L, 122L, 120L, 
130L, 127L, 128L, 127L, 132L, 122L, 120L, 127L, 128L, 127L, 121L
)), .Names = c("date", "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I best accomplish my objective with R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Among many.

```
extend_df <- function(events, priors, data) {

require(dplyr)

monthly <- list()
for (i in seq_along(events)) {

  to <- events[i]
  from <- priors[i]

  monthly[[i]] <- data %>%
    filter(date > from & date < to) %>% 
    summarise(n = sum(x)) %>% 
    pull(n)


  }
return(monthly)
}

Events %>% mutate(d = extend_df(EventDate, ThirtyDaysPriorEvent, Activities))

        date  a    b     c     d
1 2018-10-31 42 60.5 152.4 16.63
2 2018-11-16 54 54.1 151.6 16.63
3 2018-12-02 63 74.2 153.5 19.95
```

Comment: Having a `library` call inside your function definition means that you're loading the library every time you call that function

Comment: Glad it worked for @codeinspired. Changed `library()` to `require()` thanks to @camille's caution.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways I'd approach it that depend on how it fits into your workflow. The `purrr::map` family of functions makes it easy to map over these vectors rather than looping. In this case, `map2` will map simultaneously over a pair of vectors.

First thing I'd note is that since you're working with dates, you'd do well to treat them as such and convert to the `Date` class.

Another thing is that it's unclear whether you want your endpoints when you filter to be *inclusive* or *exclusive*. I'm using `dplyr::between` as a shorthand, but that will be inclusive of endpoints. I'll let you adjust as needed.

One way is to map over the two vectors of dates with `map2_dfr` to return a data frame, filter `Activities`, group by the starting date, and summarize. That gets you a data frame, which you can then join with `Events`, provided you've converted its dates to real `Date`s.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

sums_df <- map2_dfr(as.Date(EventDate), as.Date(ThirtyDaysPriorEvent), function(e, e30) {
  activities30dys <- Activities %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    filter(between(date, e30, e)) %>%
    group_by(date = e) %>%
    summarise(d = sum(x, na.rm = T))

  activities30dys
})

Events %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  left_join(sums_df, by = "date")
#>         date  a    b     c     d
#> 1 2018-10-31 42 60.5 152.4 16.63
#> 2 2018-11-16 54 54.1 151.6 16.63
#> 3 2018-12-02 63 74.2 153.5 19.95
```

Another option is to do a similar `map2`, but with `map2_dbl` to return a single numeric vector. You can then `mutate` to add this as a column to `Events`.

```r
sums_dbl <- map2_dbl(as.Date(EventDate), as.Date(ThirtyDaysPriorEvent), function(e, e30) {
  activities30dys <- Activities %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    filter(between(date, e30, e))

  sum(activities30dys$x, na.rm = T)
})

Events %>%
  mutate(d = sums_dbl)
#>         date  a    b     c     d
#> 1 2018-10-31 42 60.5 152.4 16.63
#> 2 2018-11-16 54 54.1 151.6 16.63
#> 3 2018-12-02 63 74.2 153.5 19.95
```

One last note is that rather than storing vectors of both your event dates and the date 30 days before, you can just calculate that prior date as you go. If you've converted to `Date`, then `e - 30` gives you the date 30 days before, and you can build your workflow instead like this:

```r
map(as.Date(EventDate), function(e) {
  e30 <- e - 30
  # ...
})
```

Comment: thanks for sharing some great ideas, and options for solving the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that we could probably do a full dplyr solution for this, but not without significantly reshaping the data.

So I've provided a simple for-loop solution, mostly re-using code you've written. The small modifications are for code legibility's sake:

```
#-- Initialize d
Events$d <- NA

#-- Run loop
for (i in 1:nrow(Events)) {
  e <- Events$date[i]
  e30 <- e - 30
  Events$d[i] <- Activities %>%
    filter(between(date, e30, e)) %>%
    summarize(x = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    pull()
}
```